# How to split the time from hh:mm:ss to hh mm ss in unix?

Tags: bash, date, awk

My input is

```
 ./filename Apr 11 16 05:10:20 Jun 12 16 06:22:35
```

I want to convert `Apr 11 16 05:10:20` to `16 04 11 05 10 20`
I am using the following function,

```
convert_date_2() 
{
local months=( Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec )
local i

for (( i=0; i<11; i++ ))
do
[[ $1 = ${months[$i]} ]] && break
done
printf "%2d %02d %02d %02d %02d %02d \n" $3 $(( i+1 )) $2 $4 $5 $6
}

Start=$( convert_date_2 $1 $2 $3 $4 )
Stop=$( convert_date_2 $5 $6 $7 $8 )
echo $Start;
echo $Stop;
```

But I am getting output like `16 04 11 05 00 00` and `16 06 12 06 00 00`. I actually I want `16 04 11 05 10 20` and `16 06 12 06 22 35`.

How can I modify this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply do it with `date` command itself.

```
date -d 'Apr 11 2016 05:10:20' '+%y %m %d %H %M %S'
```

**Test:**

```
$ date -d 'Apr 11 2016 05:10:20' '+%y %m %d %H %M %S'
16 04 11 05 10 20

$ var_date="Jun 12 2016 06:22:35"
$ date -d "$var_date" '+%y %m %d %H %M %S'
16 06 12 06 22 35
```

*Note:* Here, input date format have year as `2016` not `16`.

**Update:**

Try this :

```
$ var_date="Jun 12 16 06:22:35"
$ date -d "$(echo $var_date | awk '$3="20"$3')" '+%y %m %d %H %M %S'

$ date -d "$(awk '$3="20"$3' <<< $var_date)" '+%y %m %d %H %M %S'
```

Comment: Thanks. But I cannot use `2016` since my log file has data in the format `16` for year. I cannot change the format. Is it possible to use `16` for year? How can I store the result in a variable? Will `Start=$( convert_date_2 $1 $2 $3 $4 )` work?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code to this:

```
convert_date_2()  {
   local months='JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec'
   local p="${months%$1*}"
   printf "%2d %02d %02d %s\n" $3 $(( ${#p} / 3 +1)) $2 "${4//:/ }"
}

start=$(convert_date_2 $1 $2 $3 $4)
stop=$(convert_date_2 $5 $6 $7 $8)
echo "start=$start"
echo "sop=$stop"
```

[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/yr4xmh)

An example call to your new function:

```
convert_date_2 Apr 11 16 05:10:20
16 04 11 05 10 20
```

Comment: Thanks.Can you please explain $3 $(( ${#p} / 3 +1)) $2 "${4//:/ }" part of the code?

Comment: `$(( ${#p} / 3 +1))` is dividing length of `$p` by 3 and then adding `1` to the result to get the month #